Orthogonal projection of a function onto kernel of linear operator
Let $T : L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ be a linear operator defined by
$$Tf(x) = x\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(t)\mbox{d}t + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(t)\mbox{d}t \quad \hbox{for } x \in [0,1]$$
I want to find an orthgonal projection of $g(x) = x^2$ onto $\hbox{ker} T$.
My idea was to find the basis of $\hbox{ker}T^\perp$ and then find an orthogonal projection $P$ on that basis and use the fact that orthogonal projection onto $\hbox{ker}T$ will be given by $I - P$. But I have a problem with the very beginning, so how does the $\hbox{ker}T^\perp$ look like.
Edit. Is it just $\hbox{span}\left(1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(x), 1_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}(x)\right)$?

Your idea is fine as the orthogonal complement of $\ker T$ is small. The space $\ker T$ consists  of functions satisfying $$\int_0^{1/2}f(t)\,dt =\int_{1/2}^1f(t)\,dt=0$$ i.e. $f\in \ker T$ iff $f\perp   {\bf 1}_{[0,1/2]}$ and $f\perp   {\bf 1}_{[1/2,1]}.$
The orthogonal complement is thus  two dimensional and spanned by $g_1={\bf 1}_{[0,1/2]} $ and $g_2={\bf 1}_{[1/2,1]} .$ As $g_1\perp g_2,$ the orthogonal projection onto $\ker T$ of a function $f$ is equal $$f-{\langle f,g_1\rangle\over  \langle g_1,g_1\rangle}g_1-{\langle f,g_2\rangle\over  \langle g_2,g_2\rangle}g_2$$ Observe that $\langle g_k,g_k\rangle =1/2.$ Plug in $f(x)=x^2$ and perform the calculations.
